# Show that f is onto.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness, connectedness

Let $X$ be a compact connected Hausdorff space and $f:X\rightarrow X$ a continuous open map. Show that f is onto.

Comment: Let $f(X)\neq X$, $y \in X \setminus f(X) $, $x \in f(X)$. Since $X$ is Hausdorff. There are $U_i$, $V_i$ such that $x \in U_i$, $y \in Vi$ , $U_i \cap V_i=\emptyset$

Comment: Since $X$ compact, $f$ continuous $f(X)$ compact.

Comment: $f(X)\subset \bigcup _{i} U_i$ is open cover and as $f(X)$ compact $f(X)\subset \bigcup^n _{i} U_i$

Comment: As X hausdorff and $f(X)\subset X$ is compact then $f(X)$ is closed. Then $X \setminus f(X)$ is open.

Comment: How can I obtain contradiction ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $X$ is compact, $f(X)$ must be compact, hence closed, because $X$ is a Hausdorff space. But $f$ is an open map, hence $f(X)$ must be open, too. Since in a connected space the only open and closed sets are the empty set and the space itself, the map $f$ must be surjective.

Comment: @math_man: I accepted the suggested edit, but "clopen" is a widespread term for sets that are both open and closed : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set

Comment: Sorry I didn't know this term. I was trying to help people, that like me did not know this mean. Thanks for comment!